# Python class for organizing images for machine learning

Tags: python, object-oriented, image, machine-learning

I built a class to help me handle image data to use in machine learning. I thought that there would be a pre-existing package that did what I wanted but I couldn't find it so I wrote this. I am not intentionally trying to re-invent the wheel so if there's something that already does this please let me know (although I would still be interested in how I could make this better).

The main goal is the have a class of functions that can read images files from directories and convert them into training and testing sets ready for machine learning. I want to have the flexibility to return the data in any of the following forms:

- grayscale or rgb
- flattened vectors or not
- any square image size
- rescaled, standardized, or not
- labels as either column vector or not ( (n,) or (n, 1) )
- number of samples either as first or last in ndarray

I use this class to accept directories in the following format:

```
data
│
└───train
│   └───image1
│   │     im1.jpg
│   │     im2.jpg
│   └───image2
│         im1.jpg
│         im2.jpg
└───test
│   └───image1
│   │     im3.jpg
│   │     im4.jpg
│   └───image2
│         im3.jpg
│         im4.jpg
```

then return data in any format I want, including (N, l, w, 3), (N, l*w*1), (l*w*3, N), etc.

The function `train_test_sets` is the meat of the class, but there are other helper functions as well.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
import random

class Gather_Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.X_train_ = None
        self.X_test_ = None
        self.y_train_ = None
        self.y_test_ = None
        self.image_size_ = None
        self.num_train_images_ = None
        self.num_test_images_ = None

    def get_filenames(self, path):
        '''
        Returns list of filenames in a path
        '''
        # os.path.join will add the trailing slash if it's not already there
        files = [file for file in os.listdir(
            path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file))]
        return files

    def get_images(self, path, result_format='list of PIL images', new_size=0, grayscale=True):
        '''
        Accepts a path to a directory of images and
        returns an ndarray of shape N, H, W, c where
        N is the number of images
        H is the height of the images
        W is the width of the images\
        c is 3 if RGB and 1 if grayscale

        result can be "ndarray" for a single large ndarray,
        "list of ndarrays", or list of PIL Images (PIL.Image.Image)

        If a new_size is added, it must be square

        This function also allows the images to be resized, but forces square
        '''
        files = self.get_filenames(path)
        images = []
        for file in files:
            image = Image.open(os.path.join(path, file))
            if grayscale:
                image = image.convert("L")
            if new_size != 0:
                image = image.resize((new_size, new_size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            if result_format == 'ndarray' or result_format == 'list of ndarrays':
                image = np.array(image)
            images.append(image)
        if result_format == 'ndarray':
            return np.asarray(images)
        else:
            return images

    def make_dir_if_needed(self, folder):
        '''
        Checks if a directory already exists and if not creates it
        '''
        if not os.path.isdir(folder):
            os.makedirs(folder)

    def augment_images(self, original_file, output_path, output_prefix,
                       image_number, datagen, count=10):
        '''
        This function works on a single image at a time.
        It works best by enumerating a list of file names and passing the file and index.

        original_file must be the full path to the file, not just the filename

        The image_number should be the index from the enumeration e.g.:
        for index, file in enumerate(train_files):
            augment_images(os.path.join(train_path, file), output_path,
                            str(index), datagen, count=10)
        '''
        self.make_dir_if_needed(output_path)

        # load image to array
        image = img_to_array(load_img(original_file))
        # set_trace()
        # reshape to array rank 4
        image = image.reshape((1,) + image.shape)

        # let's create infinite flow of images
        images_flow = datagen.flow(image, batch_size=1)
        for index, new_images in enumerate(images_flow):
            if index >= count:
                break
            # we access only first image because of batch_size=1
            new_image = array_to_img(new_images[0], scale=True)

            output_filename = output_path + output_prefix + image_number + \
                '-' + str(index+1) + '.jpg'

            new_image.save(output_filename)

    def train_test_sets(self, input1_training_path, input2_training_path, input1_testing_path,
                        input2_testing_path, new_size=256, grayscale=False, num_samples_last=False,
                        standardization='normalize', seed=None, verbose=False,
                        y_as_column_vector=False, flatten=True):
        '''
        This assumes the data arrives in the form (N, H*W*c) where c is color
        color is 3 for RGB or 1 for grayscale
        To leave the images at their original size pass `new_size = 0`
        '''

        # Get an ndarray of each group of images
        # Array should be N * H * W * c
        train1 = self.get_images(
            input1_training_path, result_format='ndarray', new_size=new_size, grayscale=grayscale)
        train2 = self.get_images(
            input2_training_path, result_format='ndarray', new_size=new_size, grayscale=grayscale)
        test1 = self.get_images(
            input1_testing_path, result_format='ndarray', new_size=new_size, grayscale=grayscale)
        test2 = self.get_images(
            input2_testing_path, result_format='ndarray', new_size=new_size, grayscale=grayscale)

        self.image_size_ = (new_size, new_size)

        # make sure the image is square
        assert train1.shape[1] == train1.shape[2] == new_size
        # Now we have an array of images N * W * H * 3 or N * W * H * 1

        if flatten:
            if verbose:
                print("flattening")
            # Flatten the arrays
            if grayscale:
                flattened_size = new_size * new_size
            else:
                flattened_size = new_size * new_size * 3

            train1 = train1.reshape(train1.shape[0], flattened_size)
            train2 = train2.reshape(train2.shape[0], flattened_size)
            test1 = test1.reshape(test1.shape[0], flattened_size)
            test2 = test2.reshape(test2.shape[0], flattened_size)

        # Combine the two different inputs into a single training set
        training_images = np.concatenate((train1, train2), axis=0)
        # Do same for testing set
        testing_images = np.concatenate((test1, test2), axis=0)

        # Get the number of training and testing examples
        self.num_train_images_ = len(training_images)
        self.num_test_images_ = len(testing_images)

        # Create labels
        training_labels = np.concatenate(
            (np.zeros(len(train1)), np.ones(len(train2))))
        testing_labels = np.concatenate(
            (np.zeros(len(test1)), np.ones(len(test2))))

        # Zip the images and labels together so they can be shuffled together
        if verbose:
            print("zipping")
        train_zipped = list(zip(training_images, training_labels))
        test_zipped = list(zip(testing_images, testing_labels))

        if verbose:
            print("shuffling")
        # Now shuffle both
        random.seed(seed)
        random.shuffle(train_zipped)
        random.shuffle(test_zipped)

        self.X_train_, self.y_train_ = zip(*train_zipped)
        self.X_test_, self.y_test_ = zip(*test_zipped)

        # Convert tuples back to ndarrays
        self.X_train_ = np.asarray(self.X_train_)
        self.X_test_ = np.asarray(self.X_test_)
        self.y_train_ = np.asarray(self.y_train_)
        self.y_test_ = np.asarray(self.y_test_)

        if standardization == 'normalize':
            if verbose:
                print("standardizing")
            # Standardize the values
            self.X_train_ = (self.X_train_ - self.X_train_.mean()
                             ) / self.X_train_.std()
            # Use the train mean and standard deviation
            self.X_test_ = (self.X_test_ - self.X_train_.mean()
                            ) / self.X_train_.std()
        elif standardization == 'rescale':
            if verbose:
                print("standardizing")
            # Standardize the values
            self.X_train_ = self.X_train_ / 255.
            # Use the train mean and standard deviation
            self.X_test_ = self.X_test_ / 255.

        if y_as_column_vector:
            # Reshape the y to matrix them n X 1 matricies
            self.y_train_ = self.y_train_.reshape(self.y_train_.shape[0], 1)
            self.y_test_ = self.y_test_.reshape(self.y_test_.shape[0], 1)

        if num_samples_last:
            # Code conversion for class
            self.X_train_.shape = (
                self.X_train_.shape[1], self.X_train_.shape[0])
            self.X_test_.shape = (self.X_test_.shape[1], self.X_test_.shape[0])
            self.y_train_.shape = (
                self.y_train_.shape[1], self.y_train_.shape[0])
            self.y_test_.shape = (self.y_test_.shape[1], self.y_test_.shape[0])

    def dataset_parameters(self):
        '''
        Returns the parameters of the dataset
        '''
        try:
            print("X_train shape: " + str(self.X_train_.shape))
            print("y_train shape: " + str(self.y_train_.shape))
            print("X_test shape: " + str(self.X_test_.shape))
            print("y_test shape: " + str(self.y_test_.shape))
            print("Number of training examples: " + str(self.num_train_images_))
            print("Number of testing examples: " + str(self.num_test_images_))
            print("Each image is of size: " + str(self.image_size_))

        except AttributeError:
            print("Error: The data has not been input or is incorrectly configured.")
```

Here are some sample use cases:

Augmenting images:

`augment_images` uses the augmentation functionality of Keras, but gives me more flexibility. I know Keras has `save_to_dir` and `save_prefix` arguments, but I wanted to control exactly which images were augmented, how many times they were augmented, and what their files names are.

```
my_data = Gather_Data()
image_path = 'img/'
aug_path = 'aug/'
filenames = my_data.get_filenames(image_path)
# This import is down here because it would normally be in a separate file
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=45
)
for index, file in enumerate(filenames):
        my_data.augment_images(os.path.join(image_path, file), aug_path,
                               'augmented_image', str(index), datagen, count=2)
```

Getting data:

```
im1_train_path = 'data/train/im1/'
im2_train_path = 'data/train/im2/'
im1_test_path = 'data/test/im1/'
im2_test_path =  'data/test/im2/'
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
my_data.train_test_sets(im1_train_path, im2_train_path, im1_test_path, im2_test_path)
X_train = my_data.X_train_
y_train = my_data.y_train_
X_test = my_data.X_test_
y_test = my_data.y_test_
my_data.dataset_parameters()
```

I'm not particularly concerned with line length or blank lines, but I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What type of images are you using? Are they so specific that you can't find a pre-trained model and then modify that model's weights (i.e. [transfer learning](https://medium.com/@14prakash/transfer-learning-using-keras-d804b2e04ef8)? I'm assuming you're goal is some sort of classification, in which case I can't imagine you're getting impressively accurate results with an image dataset contained on your hard disk...

Comment: I'm using standard jpg images. And I am using transfer learning (among other techniques). But even in that case, I find it necessary to convert my images to the right size, shape, color scheme, etc.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I understand the desire to transform images. My comment was more directed at the seemingly unnecessary implementation of a directory scraper looking for images provided by your hard disk. Irrelevant to the desire of image transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `train_test_sets` method limit you to two folders, why? In the directory tree you provided, you only have `image1` and `image2`, but what if there's an `image3` some day? The obvious solution is to pass arrays to your method instead of a specific number of image directories.

---

I'll tackle the issue of *naming*.

- Classes should have nouns as name, not verbs. The reason behind this is that a class actually does nothing before its methods are called. So `Gather_Data` isn't a good name for a class, it would be a good name for a method.
- Using trailing underscores don't really bring anything useful to your code base, so `X_train_` should be `X_train`.

Apart from that your naming is pretty good.

---

Your method `train_test_sets` should return the sets, kind of like `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` does. Keeping them in the object only to fetch them later isn't usual and this means if someone else looked at your code, it would be "harder" to understand what the code does.

---

There's a pretty big problem with your class and it's that it does **way too many things**. It's used to : Find files, create directories, split train/test data, transform images, augment images and I'm maybe missing some. That creates many small different responsibilities that are stacked together into one class, where that should be many different methods. In my opinion, you don't need a class to load data, unless there's some complex mechanism when loading that require multiple operations.

I think you should split this class in multiple methods.

---

On a side note, shuffling the test set is useless. Shuffling the training set is to make sure the algorithm doesn't end up seeing a pattern inside the training data, but when it comes to the evaluation data, shuffling has no value.

In your `rescale` transformation, you state in comments that you use the `mean` and `std` to normalize the data, but you don't do it. That's because you copy/pasted the code from the other standardization method. Which is exactly the problem with comments. You shouldn't write them unless you're sure someone reading your code would have no idea what's going on, otherwise they can end up being ignored by people used to the code and they become deprecated. Having bad comments is worst than having no comments.

---

You use strings as enums to standardize your dataset. The problem with this is that first, other developers won't know what are the possible options, the second problem is that it's so easy to mistyep (see what I did there) a word and end up with the bug where I think my data is standardized, but it's not and it takes me hours to find out I made a spelling mistake in one of the parameters. You should reuse the pattern `opencv` has of using `int` values masked behind constants (so... enums)